# Multiple PHP Versions / cPanel with mod_fcgid

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I'm trying to get multiple PHP versions working on a cPanel server which was compiled with mod_fcgid and PHP 5.3.

Below is the PHP config generated by cPanel.

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php5
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php4
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php3
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php2
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .phtml
```

I did compiled PHP 5.2 from source and placed it's files under /usr/local/php52 then created a wrapper as below;

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/local/php52/bin/php-cgi
```

Then added the below to Apache's PHP configuration file.

```
AddHandler fcgid-script-php52 .php52
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php52 .php52
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach for this. Now what I wonder is how I can have a specific account to utilize this wrapper instead of default one?

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper is looking good as you have compiled the php52 at /usr/local/php52/. make sure that its executable.

> chmod a+x file

Also its ownership. use the chown command to do that. Its better for you to go through the following link to get the complete steps to use the [mod_fcgid](http://typo3.org/documentation/article/using-php-with-mod-fcgid/)